# Unable to make remote JNDI calls from my local EJBs

Tags: jboss, jndi

I am using jboss-5.0.1 GA.
I am trying to invoke EJB deployed on remote JBoss server from my local EJB using JNDI.

I have included the remote interfaces jar file in my local EJB project's class path. I have as well added jnp-client.jar, jboss-ejb3-client.jar in my class path.

I have started JBoss on remote machine with -b 0.0.0.0 flags to ensure it accepts remote connections.

Here is the code.

```
    SatheBeanRemote sbr = null;  //Is the remote interface for the remote bean
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://10.73.17.76:1099"); //remote Jboss IP
    p.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
    p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
    Context context;
    try {
        context = new InitialContext(p);            
        sbr = (SatheBeanRemote) context.lookup("RemoteEAR/SatheBean/remote");

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am getting the below exception.

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: Unexpected Error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netapp/beans/SatheBeanRemote
at com.netapp.balaji.greeting.GreetingBean.sayGreeting(GreetingBean.java:78)
```

Can anyone help me point out the issue ?

Comment: Looks like your app cannot see the .jar with the EJB interfaces you imported into the project. It'd be useful to see the structure of the .ear file you are using for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, You have to add EJB Project in your client folder's class path, It may resolve the problem